# How to use vuex action in function

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm new to Vue, so it's likely I misunderstand something.  I want to call a vuex action inside a local function in `App.vue` like so:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="runFunction(1)">Test</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default{
  data() { return { } },
  methods: {
      ...mapActions(['doAction']),
      buttonClicked: (input) => { runFunction(input) }
  }
}

function runFunction(input){
  doAction({ ID: input });
}
</script>
```

The action calls a mutation in `store.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    IDs: []
  },
  mutations: {
    doAction: (state, id) => { state.IDs.push(id) }
  },
  actions: {
    doAction: ({ commit }, id) => { commit('doAction', id) }
  }
})
```

I also have a main.js that sets up the vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ReferenceError: doAction is not defined
  at runFunction
```

How can I call the mapped action inside a function?  Version is Vue 2.6.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with defining `runFunction` as a 'local function':

```js
function runFunction(input){
  doAction({ ID: input });
}
```

Firstly, this is just a normal JavaScript function and the usual scoping rules apply. `doAction` would need to be defined somewhere that this function can see it. There is no magic link between this function and the component defined in `App.vue`. The function will be accessible to code in the component, such as in `buttonClicked`, but not the other way around.

The next problem is that it won't be available within your template. When you write `runTemplate(1)` in your template that's going to be looking for `this.runTemplate(1)`, trying to resolve it on the current instance. Your function isn't on the current instance. Given your template includes `@click="runFunction(1)"` I'm a little surprised you aren't seeing a console error warning that the click handler is undefined.

`mapActions` accesses the store by using the reference held in `this.$store`. That reference is created when you add the `store` to your `new Vue({store})`. The store may appear to be available by magic but it's really just `this.$store`, where `this` is the current component.

It isn't really clear why you're trying to write this function outside of the component. The simplest solution is to add it to the `methods`. It'll then be available to the template and you can access `doAction` as `this.doAction`.

To keep it as a separate function you'd need to give it some sort of access to the store. Without knowing why you want it to be separate in the first place it's unclear how best to achieve that.

Comment: There's really no reason for it to be a separate function other than in practice it ends up being a bit long.  I tried changing it to `buttonClicked: (input) => { this.doAction({ ID: input }); }` and got `TypeError: _this.doAction is not a function`

Comment: @DavidStarkey That's because you're using an arrow function. It should be `buttonClicked (input) { this.doAction({ID: input}) }`.

Comment: That was it.  Semi-beginning to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is not defined outside your instance .... you have to import the exported `store` from `store.js` on your function component :

```js
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

import store from 'store.js'

export default{
  data() { return { } },
  methods: {
      ...mapActions(['doAction']),
      buttonClicked: (input) => { runFunction(input) }
  }
}

function runFunction(input){
  store.commit({ ID: input });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't mention this in the OP, but what does having store in `new Vue({ el: '#app', store, render: h => h(App) })` in `main.js` do then?

Comment: @DavidStarkey the `this` of your vue instance is undefined outside of the `export` block

Comment: @DavidStarkey new Vue({ el: '#app', store, render: h => h(App) }) that just sets the store you exported as you instance store so `this.$store = store`

Comment: @DavidStarkey have you tried the code and it didnt work ?

Comment: I'm just unsure what the point of having actions and using `mapActions` is if you are just going to use the store directly.  Why not just do `store.state.IDs.push` at that point?